# php date() vs mysql MONTH()

Tags: php, mysql, date

i have this unix timestamp value: 1275364800 (1st june 2010).

When printing that value with php:
`echo date('m',1275364800)`
it returns 6 (thats ok)

But when i select a field from a database: `select MONTH(FROM_UNIXTIME(1275364800)) AS month` it returns 5

**Why?**

BTW, if i run this query **select FROM_UNIXTIME(1275364800) AS q** i get **2010-05-31 23:00:00**

Comment: Could it be timezone issues?  On my machine both return `6`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `1275364800` is `2010-05-31` not `1st june 2010` in mysql's locale. Are these being run on different machines?

Comment: actually both are being run in the same machine... that's what i don't get.

Answer (score 1):

To set locales in MySql do the following.

First check what your local is:

```
mysql> SELECT @@lc_time_names;
+-----------------+
| @@lc_time_names |
+-----------------+
| en_US           |
+-----------------+
```

To make sure its using the correct, If this is corrent the change your apache / php locale.

To change you locale in MySql

```
mysql> SET lc_time_names = 'en_UK';    
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)
```

en_UK being what you wish to change it to!

```
mysql> SELECT @@lc_time_names;
+-----------------+
| @@lc_time_names |
+-----------------+
| en_UK           |
+-----------------+
```

Hope this helps you!.

Comment: hi, i did that, but after doing: "SET lc_time_names = 'en_UK';" changes dont get saved, and everything remains as en_US

Comment: Have your tried using GLOBAL, SET GLOBAL LC_TIME_NAMES = 'en_UK';